# Android Studio - Build AAR to combine multiple modules/libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've created a new Android Studio project, its a library.  I've imported 5 modules (libraries/sources).

I've got them all listed in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile project(':UserVoiceSDK');
    compile project(':woopraAndroidSDK');
    compile project(':androidstripeconnect');
    compile project(':android-deferred');
    compile project(':supertooltips');
    compile project(':aFileChooser');
}
```

The final AAR file that gets made doesn't have any classes in it, I was expecting it to have the classes from all the modules.

How do I get all the classes from the modules to show up in the final AAR file? (So that they can be used in my App project)

(Previously I had these modules as part of my Android app in a similar manner, and their classes get included in the APK in that scenario).

Comment: I've concluded this isn't possible. Instead I'm publishing separate AAR files for each module.

Comment: It is possible. https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar